# How to test a complete application flow with Detox?

Tags: detox

I have started integrating `detox` into my React Native application for some e2e `testing`.

It works great so far, however I've hit a hurdle. I'm trying to test a successful login, and the flow is effectively:

1. User inputs correct credentials
2. Redux will:

   - Store User object in Async Storage
   - Register the User with Intercom
   - Trigger a success action
   - Redirect the User to Home screen - `navigateToHomeScreen()`
   - Update Sentry with User credentials

`navigateToHomeScreen`:

```
const navigateToHomeScreen = () => dispatch =>
  dispatch(
    NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })],
    })
  );
```

In my `Home` screen, I have this as my render function:

```
<View style={styles.screen} testID="home">
  <Header
    onMenuPress={navigationMenu.toggle}
    onFilterPress={filterMenu.toggle}
  />
  <Feed {...{ navigation }} />
  <IntercomButton visible={!isActive} />
  <Search />
</View>
```

In my Detox test I have this case, which is failing:

```
it('should trigger a login', async () => {
    const loginFormEmail = element(by.id('login-form-email'));
    const loginFormPassword = element(by.id('login-form-password'));
    const loginButton = element(by.id('login-button'));

    await expect(loginFormEmail).toBeVisible();
    await expect(loginFormPassword).toBeVisible();

    await expect(element(by.id('login-activity-spinner'))).toBeNotVisible();
    await loginFormEmail.replaceText('xxx');
    await loginFormPassword.replaceText('xxx');
    await loginButton.tap();

    await expect(element(by.id('home'))).toBeVisible();
```

});

I get the following error, which says `testID="home"` cannot be found:

```
 Error: Cannot find UI Element.
    Exception with Assertion: {
      "Assertion Criteria" : "assertWithMatcher:matcherForSufficientlyVisible(>=0.750000)",
      "Element Matcher" : "(((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('home')) && !(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))) || (kindOfClass('UIScrollView') && ((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && ancestorThatMatches(((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('home')) && kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))))))",
      "Recovery Suggestion" : "Check if the element exists in the UI hierarchy printed below. If it exists, adjust the matcher so that it accurately matches element."
    }

    Error Trace: [
      {
        "Description" : "Interaction cannot continue because the desired element was not found.",
        "Error Domain" : "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
        "Error Code" : "0",
        "File Name" : "GREYElementInteraction.m",
        "Function Name" : "-[GREYElementInteraction matchedElementsWithTimeout:error:]",
        "Line" : "124"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Is this still an issue for you or have you managed to solve it?

Comment: I wasn't able to fix it but the E2E testing (on the old project) was scrapped. I would still like to know how to do it @Andrew

Comment: what happens after the login button is tapped in your app? does it make a network call and then after a short wait it would login and move to the home page, or does it move to the home page straight away?

Comment: It makes a network request and then upon success, it moves to the home page @Andrew

Comment: Two possible issues that it could be: Firstly, the testID hasn't been properly set. You should check the [view hierarchy](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.RunningTests.md#debug-view-hierarchy) to see if it is there. If it has been properly set and you are sure it exists, it could be a timing issue and is calling the test before the home page is visible. You could use the `waitFor()` with `.withTimeout()` to try an capture it properly. You can see more details on that [here](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.waitFor.md#tobevisible) @Dan

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue where I have a login flow that I was trying to test. I am using react-navigation and according to the docs you can pass a testID to tab bar but for someone reason its really flaky to detect the navigation controls (header, bottom tab bar) after user logs in. So instead I just added a testID to an element that I control that I don't have to worry about whether its being set or the order its being set on. On the home screen I set a testID on a View tag that is on my home screen and it just works without timeouts. Try not to set testIDs on stuff that you dont control if possible.

```
await expect(element(by.id('homeScreenViewTag'))).toBeVisible();
```